# CSS: hyphens: auto doesn't work for some words

Tags: html, css, hyphenation, css-hyphens

Can anyone explain why the following snippet won't correctly hyphenate the word "Sustainability"? I tested this in Google Chrome, FireFox and Safari, none of them hyphenates the word, but all of them correctly hyphenate the word "hyphenated".

**My observations so far**:

1. If the word is not capitalized, hyphenation starts working
2. If I change the `lang` attribute from `en` to `de` (german), it also starts working, although the word is an english word

```css
:root {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: system-ui;
  padding: 2rem;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <p>The word Sustainability can't be hyphenated, apparently</p>
    <p>Only if written without a capital "S", it starts working: sustainability </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also the word "Hyphenated" won't be hyphenated in your example if you write it with a capital "H", so apparently upper-/lowercase spelling makes a difference in general.

Comment: Perhaps it just works as intended.

Comment: In English a noun starting with a capital letter is a proper noun (and as such, by some style rules, should not be hyphenated). In German the convention is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's defined in the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#hyphenation

"The UA may use language-tailored heuristics to exclude certain words from automatic hyphenation. For example, a UA **might try to avoid hyphenation in proper nouns** by excluding words matching certain capitalization and punctuation patterns. Such heuristics are not defined by this specification. (Note that such heuristics will need to vary by language: English and German, for example, have very different capitalization conventions.)"

Answer (score 2):

This must be an intended behavior due to language rules. At this point, there aren't many hyphenation control mechanisms and browsers are free to decide how to do the hyphenation when `hyphens: auto`.

As a workaround, you could use soft wrap character like `U+00AD` or `&shy;` HTML entity.

Comment: Thank you! It's a shame I SO doesn't support marking multiple answers as the solution ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to avoid this behavior with **capitalized** or **uppercase** words. You must write the word **with lowercase**:

```html
<strong>Lorem <span>averyreallylongword</span> ipsum</strong>
```

And then with CSS you can do this:

```css
strong {hyphens: auto;}
span {text-transform: capitalize;} // same as you say 'Titlecase'
```

Comment: I need Titlecase, not uppercase

Comment: You can follow my example in your code: `<p>The word <span>sustainability</span> can't be hyphenated, apparently</p>`. Then in CSS `span {text-transform: capitalize;}`. Note I said "or capitalize".

Comment: Uuuh, didn't even know `capitalize` was an option! Thank you so much for getting back. (can't unvote my downvote without edit, care to edit your answer in some meaningless way? ;) )

Comment: I have already edited the answer! ;)