CSS automatic hypens don't work for english?
Why do English words fail to auto-hyphenate with lang="en" language but work fine with other languages like German?


.text {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  hyphens: auto;
}
<div class="text" lang="en">
Unbreakable
</div>
<div class="text" lang="de">
Unbreakable
</div>



I get this result in both Chrome and Firefox:

Update: changing the word to lowercase makes it hyphenate properly in English. Huh???

The lang=de hyphenation would clearly be wrong in English, so I don't know how you could call that "working fine", I have no idea about German. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens.

A word that's properly hyphenated is definitely working fine compared to one that's sticking out of its box and overlapping other content. Why do English rules insist on not hyphenating words starting with a capital letter?

That word is improperly hyphenated.

Related, if not a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146218/css-hyphens-auto-doesnt-work-for-some-words

Also, relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line. According to the first rule about morphene boundaries, I think breaking 'unbreakable' at 'unbrea' would be acceptable.

Your syllogism is absurd: it is not because a word is written the same in two different languages ​​that they necessarily apply the same typographical rules.

Different systems will have different algorithms for hyphenation, and there are no hard and fast rules for how to hyphenate in English, only various house styles created for example by publishers/printers in the days of hand typesetting.
The question asks why there is a difference when the word starts with uppercase or lowercase.
In as much as there can be an answer, in English a word beginning with an uppercase letter is known as a proper noun and is not generally hyphenated. Other nouns have the first letter in lowercase and are deemed hyphenatable.
This is a main difference with the German language where nouns tend to have the first character capitalised and are deemed hyphenatable.

Is there no distinction between proper nouns and first words in a sentence?

Well, there might be - logically - but whether every hyphenation algorithm builds in that difference or not I couldn't say. Also I understand there can be problems of non-hyphenation if CSS has been used to convert to uppercase for example. TBH if you want decent hyphenation (in the sense you personally agree it's OK) you probably end up doing at least some of it yourself - e.g. using the &shy soft hyphen.
